# MariaDB convert text to date

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT Entity.name, Entity.id, Entity.created, ComplDate.field_completion_date_value
FROM application_form_entity AS Entity
LEFT JOIN application_form_entity__field_completion_date AS ComplDate
    ON ComplDate.entity_id=Entity.id
```

The problem is that Entity.name columns are filled with - Application form (15.03.2018 00:55) as text.

How do I convert this to normal date, that I can put it in WHERE so I can specify time frame to search by.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix the table, not the query.

Comment: that is completely impossible

Comment: @MarcisTurks How so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str_to_date()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/str_to_date/).

```
SELECT str_to_date(Entity.name, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i'), Entity.id, Entity.created, ComplDate.field_completion_date_value
FROM application_form_entity AS Entity
LEFT JOIN application_form_entity__field_completion_date AS ComplDate
    ON ComplDate.entity_id=Entity.id
```

But a schema change to use the appropriate data type is highly advisable.

Comment: I agree with @sticky bit, it may be a hassle to change the column type, but in the long run it will be worth it especially if it is used a lot!

Comment: Optionally keep 2 columns -- the original string and a clean `DATETIME`.